# how to post value of 3 input field posting in arry into database

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am posting values og dynamically created input fields in array fromat

```
<form method='post' action='<?php echo site_url('a3_bus_system/output')?>'>
<div class="_25">
<strong>Route Name/Number</strong>
     <br/>
<input type="text" name=""></input>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;<p>&nbsp;</p></p>
<p>&nbsp;<p>&nbsp;</p></p>
<div id="div">
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p><div class="_25">
<p><input type="button" name="button" class="button red" id="button" value="Add"  onclick="generateRow() "/></a></p>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
 <input type="submit"  class="button blue" id="button" value="Register" />
/form>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear height-fix"></div>
</div></div> <!--! end of #main-content -->
</div> <!--! end of #main -->
<script>
var counter=1;
    function generateRow() {
    var count="<font color='red'>"+counter+"</font>";
   var temp ="  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='stop["+counter+"]' placeholder='Stop Name'></input></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='timing["+counter+"]' placeholder='Timing'></input></div>&nbsp;<div class='_25'><select id='ampm' name='ampm["+counter+"]'><option>a.m</option><option>p.m</option></select>  </div>";

var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = temp + count;

var yourDiv = document.getElementById('div');

yourDiv.appendChild(newdiv);
counter++;
    }

</script>
```

now i am using this codeigniter script to post it in data base

```
// form 1st text box input
foreach ($_POST['stop'] as $stopIndex => $stopValue) {

        $sql="INSERT INTO  t_routes_list(stop_name) VALUES('".$this->db->escape_str($stopValue)."')";

    $this->db->query($sql);

}
    // form 2nd text box input



foreach ($_POST['timing'] as $timingIndex => $timingValue)
    {

    $sql="INSERT INTO  t_routes_list(timing) VALUES('".$this->db->escape_str($timingValue)."')";

    $this->db->query($sql);
}
// form 3rd select box input
foreach ($_POST['ampm'] as $ampmIndex => $ampmValue) {
   $sql="INSERT INTO  t_routes_list(am_pm) VALUES('".$this->db->escape_str($ampmValue)."')";

    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

now 1 want to post data 1 by 1 only which is entered.. but when i am posting it all the fields getting posted by null value

how to post all data simultaneously?

coders pleas help me with the php script

Answer (score 0):

mate, in Codeigniter exists [Active Records](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

create a `models/model_insert.php` ad hoc and put inside an insert function:

```
class Model_Insert extends CI_Model{
 function insert($data){
  $this->db->insert('mytable',$data);
}


}
```

now you have just to do this in your controller to insert some data in "mytable":

```
$this->load->model('model_insert');
$data = array('id'=>$id,'email'=>$email);
$this->model_insert->insert($data);
```